# Tomcat, two Java versions and "invalid constant type: 18"

Tags: tomcat, version, java

I have a problem with deploying my app to Tomcat. I have Tomcat on a Docker containter, java -version gives output like this:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.6.0) (Alpine 8.151.12-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

The app was build on a Windows machine, using:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

When trying to start the app I get:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:967)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:910)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:127)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:630)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:52)
```

One more thing - the app build on the Windows machine is running perfectly fine on the server with Java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

What should I do in this situation? Build the app on OpenJDK? Change the version?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be related to exact JVM version - constant type "18" is used since java 7. Maybe container/Tomcat ships with outdated javassist version - older than 3.16.0-GA.

Comment: Tomcat doesn't ship with javassist. This is a web application issue, not an Tomcat issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use higher version javassist jar. if you are using maven, make the following pom entry for java assist.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the dependencies tree using MVN and check whether you've added multiple versions from javassist library.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

If do, **Remove the older version and keep the latest javassist** with the application.